# Shortcut for finding references of CSS class in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Normally, you can right-click on a method and  select "Go To Definition" (F12) or "Find All References" (SHIFT+F12). You can even go to the definition of a css class from your aspx page by pressing F12 (if your cursor is over the CssClass name).

Is there a similar shortcut for finding all the references of a css class from an external stylesheet? My reason for asking is that I have a stylesheet containing a bunch of css classes that may or may not be in use anymore, and I'd like to know which ones are actually being called without having to read through my code line by line.

Also, I've tried the Quick Find (CTRL+F) tool to search for a particular css class. It doesn't turn up any results even for classes that are in use, so either I'm not using it right or it doesn't bother checking my aspx page for whatever reason. (I suspect it's the former!)

PS I'm using 2010 Express edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CTRL+SHIFT+F to bring up the Find and Replace dialog. In there, make sure to verify that the search scope is set to Entire Solution, and try that.

Comment: I've tried this and it wasn't working. If the name of my css class is .background4, I get no results if i type in background4 or even CssClass="background4" which is exactly what is present in the aspx page. Why?

Comment: oh actually never mind. I was doing CTRL+F but apparently CTRL+SHIFT+F is different and that works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to use Find Dialog, are there any vs extensions for that? There are some for vs code, but nothing for vs!